# PHP / SQL - How to update a database field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

so I have in my website a table of clients with several columns such as name, age, etc, etc... and I have added a new column which is "Delete" and I added checkboxes, and there's also a button, what I want to do is, if I select one or more checkboxes, and then click on the button to delete, I want them to be deleted off the website but then on the database I want to a field to be updated from 0 to 1 whereas 0 means the client exists on both website and database and 1 means that it no longer exists on the website but it still exists on database.

I'm new in the area of programming but this is the code I got so far:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

if(isset($_POST['option']) == 'check' && ($_POST['button']) == 'submit') {

$query = "UPDATE commande

SET traiter = 1

WHERE id = '%$id%'";

var_dump($query);

}
```

Now this doesn't work, he is not doing the update correctly, I select the checkbox and then click on the button and it doesn't delete from the website nor updates the database specific field from the right client based on its' id, and I have no idea why!

Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: You're using `LIKE` syntax in a simple comparison. Remove the percent signs after `WHERE`. Also: obligatory [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) reference.

Comment: You don't seem to be executing the query?

Comment: You're right @Epodax and that's the problem, I don't get it why it's not working right

Answer (score 2):

You can use this by two ways:

1-If more than one id(s) are coming then :

```
$query = "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id IN ($id)";
```

2-If only one id will update at a time then:

```
$query = "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `=` remove `%`

```
$query = "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
```

or use `LIKE` with `%`

```
$query = "UPDATE commande SET traiter= 1 WHERE id LIKE '%$id%'";
```

Comment: Using 'like' with $id doesn't make sense

Comment: Oh true, lack of attention of mines, already corrected that small detail but still doesn't work, I'm using var_dump to debug it, and when I execute the action I want to do I get this message from var_dump: string(56) "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id LIKE '%%'"

Comment: run this query on **UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id = '$id'** MySQL  and check working fine or not ???? @LeFuture

Comment: But usually we use id as an primary key. I don't think id will be like 'abc001'

Comment: check first is variable $id = $_POST['id']; contain value or NOT..  debug your script... solution would be there

Comment: @Rahautos it shows this error with var_dump: string(54) "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id LIKE ''"

Comment: don't use like use ***UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id = '$id'** @LeFuture

Comment: @SunnyS.M I've did what you suggested and the var_dump shows me "NULL", now wondering why and how to correct it

Comment: i think value of **$_POST['id']** is blank @LeFuture

Comment: @Rahautos my goal is that if a checkbox is selected and I click the button to delete, he deletes that line, and updates the field in the database, but for that to be possible he needs to check which client it is, through its' id correct? That's the flaw right now, he isn't checking through the id

Comment: Dear brother debug your script and check form posted all variable properly? 1) check form input name must be match with $_POST['NameMustBeMatchHere']  2) Check through var_dump($_POST)  it will print all form values.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple select checkbox for delete**

Considering that `$id` is an array, You can use`IN` clause to replace many OR conditions.

You can use `in` clause in where condition like

```
$query = "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 1 WHERE id IN ($id)";
```

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

**Update**

You should treat it as an array like this,

```
 <input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
 <input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
 <input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="3">
 <input name="id[]" type="checkbox" value="4">
```

Then only, you can take it as an array. So, `$_POST['id']` will provide array of selected checkbox.

Comment: $id is not an array, I just created a php variable named $id = $_POST['id']; to say that $id is equal to database field 'id'

Comment: There are many checkbox, right ? Keep that each checkbox name same and post the data. then you will get array

Comment: All the checkboxes already have the same name, I've already covered that, the problem here is directly related to the query

Comment: Dude, your multiple condition in query can be done as I shown in my answer. Checkbox name should be like this id[] for each checkbox. So, $_POST['id'] will provide array of selected checkbox.

Comment: so basically you're saying, in checkbox I put name="id[]" is that it?

Comment: yes, So, $_POST['id'] will provide array of selected checkbox.

Comment: Wait but I think there's one thing you didn't quite understand, I don't have ten checkboxes (for example), I have only one checkbox in my form, but it addes checkboxes in the entire column

Comment: means you are looping that checkbox for id's right ?

Comment: In my answer, I provide many inputs just for sample. If you are looping it then place there, that will apply to all rows.

Comment: Ugh, it's so hard to explain you through this, specially when I'm quite an amateur in this area, any chance we can skype chat, it's easier and quicker, yeah?

Comment: Can you update your question with your front end code i.e. form

Comment: my goal is that if a checkbox is selected and I click the button to delete, he deletes that line, and updates the field in the database, but for that to be possible he needs to check which client it is, through its' id correct? That's the flaw right now, he isn't checking through the id, and since he doesn't find the id that corresponds to the client I selected, he therefore doesn't update the field traiter from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

```
after you get id/s of delete record 

    $query = "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 0 WHERE id IN ($id)";//For multiple multiple



    $$query = "UPDATE commande SET traiter = 0 WHERE id = '$id'";//for single record
 Set traiter to '0' means deleted record and '1' for active record
```